# Use resharper to refactor a string parameter to an interface with a string property

Tags: c#, resharper

I have a constructor for a class that takes a connection string

```
public MyClass(String connectionString){

}
```

I would like it to be

```
public MyClass(IConnectionStringProvider connectionStringProvider){

}
```

where `IConnectionStringProvider` is

```
public interface IConnectionStringProvider {
   String ConnectionString { get; }
}
```

How can I perform this kind of refactoring with Resharper? (I have version 8)

Comment: What would the callsite look like if you did it manually?  Obviously, it could not be `new IConnectionStringProvider`.

Comment: new ConnectionStringProvider { ConnectionString = connectionString } would be fine

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This isn't exactly what you asked for but I think it's as close as you're going to get out of the box.

1. Put your cursor on the `MyClass` constructor.
2. From the menu: *Reshaper* -> *Refactor* -> *Extract Class From Parameters...*
3. In the dialog box enter `IConnectionStringProvider` in the *Name* textbox
4. Click *Next*
5. Change `IConnectionStringProvider` from a `class` to an `interface` and delete the additional code that was generated in the class.